# Bash: unary operator expected

Tags: bash

I have this code:

```
if [ `grep DISTRIB_ID /etc/*-release | awk -F '=' '{print $2}'` = "Ubuntu" ]; then
```

It gives me this warning:

```
bash: line 21: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

It works but the warning is not nice. I have tried other variants but these showed up this message also or did not worked. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try replacing = with -eq

Comment: Add output of `grep DISTRIB_ID /etc/*-release | awk -F '=' '{print $2}'` to your question.

Comment: Try this: `if [[ $(awk -F '=' '/DISTRIB_ID/ { print $2 }' /etc/*-release) == "Ubuntu" ]]; then`

Comment: You get this error because you didn't quote the command expansion, and it's not returning anything

Comment: Use two brackets instead of one.  `[[ ....  ]]`.  However your pipeline is poorly  written with an unnecessary `grep` - see @anubhava's comment.

Comment: No, it's not "working" -- it's giving the result you want, but for the wrong reason (because its syntax is wrong, not because the comparison failed); hence, it's not actually running that comparison at all.

Comment: btw, `==` is bad form -- see the POSIX test spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, giving the only string comparison operator allowed in POSIX `test` (the command otherwise known as `[`) as `=`. That's not your immediate bug, because bash allows `==` as an extension, but for maximum compatibility that extension is best avoided. (Alternately, if you use `[[ ]]` you're outside of POSIX-specified land, so the primary reason to prefer `=` over `==` there is establishing good finger memory for when you *are* writing for POSIX shells).

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ would have found this bug for you, without needing to get a bunch of humans involved.